# unable to insert data into my second table , sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

``I have two tables in my sqLite database, the first one is working properly but i m unable to insert data into the second table. I have a single dbadapter class and i am using contentValues in my `onCreate()` method to insert data in both tables.

I tried almost everything to make it work but everything seems useless
Here is my dbadapter code`

```
 public class MainData {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Homeomedicaldb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "basic_table";
private static final String KEY_ID = "sym_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "sym_detail_name";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "detail_table";
private static final String KEY_SYM_ID = "sym_previous_id";
private static final String KEY_DET_ID = "sym_detail_id";
private static final String KEY_SYMP_DETAIL = "sym_details";
private static final String KEY_MEDICINE = "medicine_name";

private static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
private static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + KEY_DET_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_SYMP_DETAIL + " text not null, " + KEY_MEDICINE + " text not null, " + KEY_SYM_ID + " integer, "+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_SYM_ID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLE1+" ("+KEY_ID+"));" ;


private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE1);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE2); 
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_ID, "1");
            values.put(KEY_NAME, "headache");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, values);

            values.put(KEY_ID, "2");
            values.put(KEY_NAME, "abdominal pain");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, values);

            values.put(KEY_ID, "3");
            values.put(KEY_NAME, "eye infection");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, values);

            values.put(KEY_ID, "4");
            values.put(KEY_NAME, "skin pimples");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, values);

            values.put(KEY_ID, "5");
            values.put(KEY_NAME, "infection");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, values);
 ContentValues new_values = new ContentValues();    

new_values.put(KEY_DET_ID, "1.1");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, "eye;inflammation;with headache");
            new_values.put(KEY_MEDICINE, "lycopodium");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYM_ID, "1");
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values);   
      new_values.put(KEY_DET_ID, "1.2");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, "nose;pain;with headache");
            new_values.put(KEY_MEDICINE, "lycopodium");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYM_ID, "1");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values);

            new_values.put(KEY_DET_ID, "1.3");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, "perspiration;cold;with headache");
            new_values.put(KEY_MEDICINE, "lycopodium");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYM_ID, "1");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values);

            new_values.put(KEY_DET_ID, "1.4");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, "face;heat;with headache");
            new_values.put(KEY_MEDICINE, "lycopodium");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYM_ID, "1");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values);

            new_values.put(KEY_DET_ID, "1.5");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, "perspiration;with headache");
            new_values.put(KEY_MEDICINE, "lycopodium");
            new_values.put(KEY_SYM_ID, "1");
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values); 


    }
```

this is the method i m using to show result of second table

```
    public String getDetail() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns2 = new String[]{ KEY_DET_ID, KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, KEY_MEDICINE, KEY_SYM_ID };
    Cursor v = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, columns2, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result_new= "";

    int iSym= v.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYM_ID);
    int iName = v.getColumnIndex(KEY_DET_ID);
    int iDetail = v.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL);
    int iMedicine = v.getColumnIndex(KEY_MEDICINE);
    for(v.moveToFirst(); !v.isAfterLast(); v.moveToNext()) {
        result_new= result_new+ v.getString(iSym)+ " " + v.getString(iName)+ " " + v.getString(iDetail)+ " " + v.getString(iMedicine) + "\n" ;
    }
    return result_new;
}
```

here is the logcat

```
    07-31 06:52:38.731: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1263): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-31 06:52:44.221: I/Choreographer(1263): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 06:55:18.651: D/gralloc_goldfish(1319): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-31 06:55:19.481: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 06:55:22.271: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 06:55:39.381: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 06:56:22.861: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 06:56:32.331: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 08:00:56.271: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 08:01:00.841: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 08:01:28.291: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 08:01:45.241: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 08:20:01.821: I/Choreographer(1319): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: And what is the actual problem?

Comment: post logcat for the issues

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion: this `new_values.put(KEY_SYMP_DETAIL, "eye;inflammation;with headache");` is really **suboptimal**. You should store reference integer ids to another table which contains the details. And also this: `new_values.put(KEY_MEDICINE, "lycopodium");` the same suggestion applies. Take full advantage of the "Relational" part in RDBMS!

Comment: The actual problem is that everything is working fine, the logcat not showing any errors but still data isnt getting inserted into the second table.

Comment: Please report the **LogCat**, not the **Console output**!

Comment: m sorry! i have now added logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I got the solution for this problem, posting this as it might help others,
I just changed the name of my db and the code worked all fine. Its because the SQLiteOpenHelper seems to have some troubles registering that the database is to be changed. It finds a db with the same name and version number, goes 'meh' and doesn't look to see if the structure is different at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `return` on line #64 and change `ourDatabase` to `db`

#### From

```
return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values);
```

#### To

```
db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, new_values);
```

Comment: Sorry that was typed mistakenly, but after changing it, the code is still not working